# Django - Get only date from datetime.strptime

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have start date field in database as date (not datetime). In my save method in forms.py I'm using `datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d')` to convert string to date. The method returns me formatted date along with time, i.e, "2006-08-03 00:00:00".

I want just the date and no time. Because I get an "invalid date format error" saying "It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format", I'm stuck on this and frustrated.  Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: If you are using a django form, then use a django DateField to handle the validation of it. Much more convenient.

Comment: Changing the field to DateField helped. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

I think you need date object not datetime. 
Try converting datetime to date using date() method on datetime object

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('2014-12-04', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

Comment: It would be nice to simply have strpdate()

Comment: This is definitely better than having to wrap datetime.date(result)

Comment: in which .py file to use this?

Answer (score 3):

Iazy functor's answer is very helpful. For people who want to use it as template tag:

```
from django import template
from datetime import datetime

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='todate')
def convert_str_date(value):
    return datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

Then import your template.py in your HTML and use it as:

```
{{ date_in_str|todate }}

Output: 2021.01.22
```

If you want to change the date format:

```
{{ date_in_str|todate|date:"d N Y" }}

Output: 22 Jan. 2021
```